# C++ obtaining a reference to a returned object

Tags: c++, reference

I need to grab an object by reference and I used to do it like so:

```
MyObject& obj = FactoryThatGivesAnObject();
obj.MethodThatModifieObj();
```

No I need to do it based on a conditional:

```
MyObject obj;

// Need obj to be a reference to the returned values below
if( foo )
    obj = FactoryThatGivesAnObject();
else
    obj = OtherFactoryThatGivesAnObject();

obj.MethodThatModifiesObj();
```

How can I have obj be a reference in the second example?

Comment: Why do you want it to be a reference?

Answer (score 5):

References, unlike pointers, can only be set once.  This is a useful feature many times, but this is the one frustrating aspect about it.  You only want to set the reference once, but possibly to different things.

You have two options.

1) Use the ternary operator

This is often the easiest, if you're only dealing with two factories, and a simple boolean to decide which to use:

```
MyObject& obj = ( foo
                  ? FactoryThatGivesAnObject();
                  : OtherFactoryThatGivesAnObject() );
```

However, if `foo` is more complicated, or if you have multiple factory options, the next option may be cleaner.

2) Use a factory method of your own

```
MyObject& get_an_object(const int state) // or whatever parameters you need
{
    switch(state)
    {
       case USE_LEGACY_FACTORY:    return FactoryThatGivesAnObject();
       case USE_FOO_FACTORY:       return OtherFactoryThatGivesAnObject();
       case DO_SOMETHING_ELSE:     return YetAnotherObjectFactory();
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Bad Factory Selector");
}

// usage is simpler now
MyObject& obj = get_an_object(foo);
```

Note that you may need to pass several parameters to your factory method:

- selection criteria.  Your example was just `foo` - a simple boolean.  As things grow, you may need additional criteria to help determine which factory to use.
- factory objects.  You may have factory objects instead of factory methods, in which case you need to pass references to those objects into your method.

Comment: +1 because this works even without going into pointers. Though I have concerns about the innards of the OP's factory still.

Answer (score 3):

One solution may be to use a ternary operator:

```
obj = foo ? FactoryThatGivesAnObject() : OtherFactoryThatGivesAnObject();
```

You could also use a pointer:

```
MyObject* pobj;
if( foo )
    pobj = &FactoryThatGivesAnObject();
else
    pobj = &OtherFactoryThatGivesAnObject();
```

Comment: Hmm.. there's an exception safety problem here. Why not `auto_ptr` or `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Actually, it's even worse than that. Assuming the factories return things by value, you've created a pointer to an unnamed temporary (which is obviously bad). If they return by reference then the factory needs to maintain the state of the object...

Comment: I'm making the same assumptions as the code sample in the OP.

Comment: And BTW, no exception safety issues as there is clearly no memory allocation done here.

Comment: Pointers == someone needs to free the memory somewhere.

Comment: @Billy: No, `new` == someone needs to free the memory somewhere.  Pointers == re-assignable references to objects that may or may not be dynamically allocated.  I know that if I'm using a naked pointer, I never have to free any memory, because I don't use naked pointers for dynamic memory.

Answer (score 2):

Your very first line is shady:

```
MyObject& obj = FactoryThatGivesAnObject();
```

How is that supposed to work? The factory method cannot return a reference to a temporary, so the only sensible reference it could return is to a dynamically created object - but now who is responsible for this object?

(Unless you are just returning a reference to an existing object, that is. But I'm assuming that your factory is genuinely creating new objects.)

This code is a memory-leak car crash; I don't see any way to write anything sensible like that. A far better way is to return the newly created object in a responsible container, e.g. a `shared_ptr` or a `unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<MyObject> FactoryFunction()
{
  return std::unique_ptr<MyObject>(new MyObject(3,5,7));
}
```

That way, if nobody picks up the factory product, or if an exception occurs, the dynamically allocated object will get properly disposed of.

This also makes it trivial to assign different pointers depending on a conditional:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyObject> x;

if (...)      { x = Factory1(); }
else if (...) { x = Factory2(a,b); }
else          { x = Factory3(argc, argv); }
```

Comment: These could be members to a class that owns the objects, or other situations where the factory registers the new object with some sort of pool.

Comment: @Moo: Yeah, could be. *Could* be. The OP is welcome to elaborate.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Why are you assuming that the OP does not know what he's doing?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I have obj be a reference in the second example?

You can't. References are aliases; you can only create them by pointing them at something, and once you've pointed them, they cannot be reassigned.

You would probably be better off using something like a `std::auto_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` here. Note that your factory would need to return the auto/unique_ptr though. If your factory is returning a reference I suspect you might be accidentially returning references to unnamed temporaries (unedefined behavior), but without seeing the factories' code it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Why do you assume that they might be references to unnamed temporaries? The "factory" could very well be returning references to objects in a pool for example.

Comment: @Pierre: I'm assuming that because 99% of the times I see people doing this returning references are expecting things to work like references do in Java or C#.

Comment: @Pierre: That *is* possible, but just very unlikely, and the OP is most welcome to amend her question with details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution which is not technically a factory, but solves the same problem -- providing new objects when you change parameters:

```
struct A
{
  int a;
  float x;
  int c;
};
class ObjectCollection
{
public:
    ObjectCollection() { m_a.c = 10; }
    A &get_obj_a(int a, float x)
    {
    m_a.a = a;
    m_a.x = x;
    return m_a;
    }
private:
    A m_a;
};
```

This version has advantage that it does not pass around ownership to the object, but still you can create different kinds of objects with it. Two calls to get_obj_a() will cause problems though, it only works if you call get_obj_a() immediately before you need the object. Now the if statement can be put inside the factory function. Also here's another way to do it:

```
class DerivedFactory
{
public:
   DerivedFactory(ObjectCollection1 &c, ObjectCollection2 &c2) : c(c),c2(c2) { }
   Base &get_obj_a_or_b(bool b) {
         if (b) return c.get_obj_a(10,11.0);
         else return c2.get_obj_b(20.0,13.0);
   } 
private:
  ObjectCollection1 &c;
  ObjectCollection2 &c2;
};
```