# How do I obtain a handle to one of many objects at runtime?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to choose one of many available objects at runtime without incurring the overhead of copying an object. In the code below, I illustrate what I am looking for. I have 2 `map` objects and I want to manipulate one of them at runtime based on the value of `type`. I can think of 2 possible solutions:

- Use the assignment operator using `=` - this will copy the map to another map and I want to avoid this
- Use a pointer and change the pointer to `point` to the correct map.

Can I achieve this without using pointers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

void print_map(map<string, bool> const &M, string header)
{
  map<string, bool>::const_iterator itr;

  cout << header << endl;

  for (itr=M.begin(); itr!=M.end(); itr++) {
    cout << itr->first << " -> " << itr->second << endl;
  }
  cout << " --- " << endl;
  return;
}

int main()
{
  map<string, bool> fruits;
  map<string, bool> veggies;

  fruits.insert(pair<string, bool>("apple", true));
  fruits.insert(pair<string, bool>("banana", true));
  print_map(fruits, "fruits before");

  veggies.insert(pair<string, bool>("celery", true));
  veggies.insert(pair<string, bool>("potato", true));
  veggies.insert(pair<string, bool>("radish", true));
  print_map(veggies, "veggies before");

  string type = "f";

  // obj_handle                   <---- Need help on implementing this handle
  if (type == "f") {
      // obj_handle = ?
  }
  else if (type == "v") {
      // obj_handle = ?
  }

  // Manipulate object
  // print_map(obj_handle, "Printing from handle");

  return 0;
}
```

Found another answer on SO which is related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7002278/3586654

Comment: `print_map` should take the map by `const` reference rather than by value, otherwise you'll end up making a copy of it.

Comment: Sure, I made the edit - but `print_map` was for illustration only.

Comment: How about a huge ternary expression `map& objmap = type == "f" ? fruits : type == "v" ? veggies : defaultobjects;`? Or just bite the bullet, use pointers, pass by reference.

Comment: I am not sure why you would avoid pointers for this.

Comment: @Jeff, not trying to avoid pointers - exploring other options is more like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to obtain a reference to one of the two maps. Here is one that uses a separate function. But, as @CaptainObvlious commented, you may also use an ugly-huge ternary expression to achieve the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
using ItemFlags = std::map<std::string, bool>  ;
#else
typedef std::map<std::string, bool> ItemFlags ;
#endif

void print_map(const ItemFlags& M, 
               const std::string& header)
{
    using namespace std ;
    ItemFlags::const_iterator itr;

    cout << header << endl;

    for (itr=M.begin(); itr!=M.end(); itr++) {
        cout << itr->first << " -> " << itr->second << endl;
    }
    cout << " --- " << endl;
    return;
}

const ItemFlags& select_map( const ItemFlags& fruitMap, 
                             const ItemFlags& veggieMap, 
                             const std::string& typeSelector ) 
{
    if (typeSelector == "f") {
        return fruitMap ;
    } 
    if (typeSelector == "v") {
        return veggieMap ;
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid type selector.") ;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std ;
    ItemFlags fruits;
    ItemFlags veggies;

    fruits.insert(pair<string, bool>("apple", true));
    fruits.insert(pair<string, bool>("banana", true));
    print_map(fruits, "fruits before");

    veggies.insert(pair<string, bool>("celery", true));
    veggies.insert(pair<string, bool>("potato", true));
    veggies.insert(pair<string, bool>("radish", true));
    print_map(veggies, "veggies before");

    string type = "f";

    const ItemFlags& selected_map = select_map(fruits, veggies, type) ;

    // Manipulate object
    print_map(selected_map, "Printing from handle");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @crayzeewulf, using a function seems cleanest since I will have more than 2 objects that I need to select from.